# php being commented out in HTML

Tags: php, html

I am building a user form and I am using php for the values of the form.

```
    <select id="customerInput" name="customerId" style="width:300px"> 
        <?  foreach (array_slice($customers, 1) as $row) { ?>
        <option value="<? echo $row['CustomerID']; ?>"> <? echo $row['Name'];  ?> </option> <? } ?>
    </select>
```

Hopefully you can see what I am trying to do...I want the options value to be the customer ID and the writing in the field the customer Name.

When I run this the and view the source, the php is commented out  etc and does not work

I am not sure why...Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `<?php ` instead of `<? ` as the starting tag?

Comment: Does your server support PHP in the first place? Have you enabled short open tag?

Comment: It supports PHP but looks like it doesn't support short open tags lol. Thanks for the help. How do I enable the short open tags?

Comment: check the ini file and set short_open_tag = 1. Learn more about php tags here http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this *(Changing `<?` to `<?php` )*:

```
<select id="customerInput" name="customerId" style="width:300px"> 
        <?php 
          foreach (array_slice($customers, 1) as $row) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $row['CustomerID']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['Name'];  ?> </option>
       <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: That worked! wow thanks! So I need to use the full hand for php?

Comment: It depends on how your server is set up. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: yes, otherwise you should enable this on your server

Comment: Also, @Butterflycode please don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: Will do, just cant for 10 more minutes :)